# Change opacity of a selected image with JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Images 1 and 2 are sitting on top of image 0. They have transparent backgrounds. Initially all 3 are shown. I need to change opacity of images 1 and 2 to 0 when the box is unchecked, and back to 1 when it is checked. It should happen individually for images 1 and 2, not together.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<style>
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 80px;
    width: 624px;
    height: 400px;
    }
.show {
        opacity: 1;
    }
.hide {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function change(checkboxElem) {
    if (checkboxElem.checked) {
        alert("checked")
    } else {
        alert("notchecked")
    }
}    
</script>>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="image0.png">
<img class="show" id="img1" src="image1.png">
<img class="show" id="img2" src="image2.png">
</div>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="change(this)" checked>Blue<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" onchange="change(this)" checked>Red<br>
</form>
</body>
```

1. I know I need to pass the value to function change, but not sure how to do that (this.value?)
2. change function should change opacity of only the selected image, not both, to 0 or 1
3. I also don't know how to write HTML/CSS to accomplish that
4. As of now, for some reason, I see > displayed at the top of the page. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: </script>>  that's your extra >

Comment: If you are editing with an IDE (or even something simple like Notepad), Ctrl+F and search for ">>" then remove one of the ">"

Comment: *"It should happen individually for images 1 and 2, not together."* If not together...how would you ever get to see image 0? Image 1 or image 2 would be visible while the other would not?

Comment: Thank you for catching >>. Image 0 is a background.It has default opacity of 1. I want it shown all the time. Images 1 and 2 are mostly transparent and are only shown if checked. 1 and 2 were saved with transparent background.

Comment: So if image 1 is visible, then image 2 must be transparent and vice versa?

Comment: No. Image 0 is always shown. Image 1 is shown if it is selected. Image 2 is shown if it is selected. 0 can be shown with 1, 2 or both of them. 1 and 2 are mostly empty saved with transparent backgrounds so images 0 behind them shows.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add an ID to the images so you can control them:

```
<img class="show" ID="img1" src="image1.png">
<img class="show" ID="img2" src="image2.png">
```

Then instead of transparency, perhaps you should use `display`:

```
function change(checkboxElem) {

    document.getElementById("img" + checkboxElem.value).style.display = (checkboxElem.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

This way, when an element is checked, the image will be displayed, and when it is removed, it will disappear.

Edit - added a jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/u6a0ze6m/5/

Comment: I understand the logic behind iding images, but I'm not sure what you mean by display instead of transparency. Transparency was only mentioned in the context of images 1 and 2. They have very little design and were saved with transparent background. Image 0 is a background. When I show all 3 with opacity of 1 it looks fine. When a checkbox is unselected for either image 1 or 2 their opacity should change to 0.

Comment: I'm assuming I need to change my input element to something like <input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="change(this.value)" checked>Blue<br>. Is that correct? I tried modifying my change function to what you suggested and could not make it to work. ids were added to images as you suggested.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the function, but now I corrected it.

You can use the display instead of opacity.
When the Checkbox is checked, the display is set 'block', which means it is visable, and if the Checkbox is not checked, the display changes to 'none' which is equivalent to zero opacity. That is, invisable.

Use now the function I wrote instead of your function, it should work.

Comment: It's still not working. Maybe I'm not passing to the function what I'm supposed to. Is it onchange="change(value)" or onchange="change(this.value)"?

Comment: You're not supposed to pass anything but `this`.
Just: `onchange = "change(this);"`
It works for me.

Comment: You're right. It does work. I'll try to figure out how and how to change it to work when I start with both checkboxes unselected to start with. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Here you go: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u6a0ze6m/7/) - added 2 lines in the JS, and all you need to do is set the `checked` mark of the `input`.

Comment: I see how your code does exactly what I want it to do. I don't think I'm pasting JS code where it's supposed to be. I'll try to understand how it works. Embarrassing. Thank you!